# Trouble solving $\lim _{x\to -\infty }\frac{3x^7-25x^5+e^{-x^3/(1-x)^3}}{-5x^7+\left(111!\right)\cdot \:x}$

Tags: calculus, limits

$$\lim _{x\to -\infty }\frac{3x^7-25x^5+e^{-\frac{x^3}{\left(1-x\right)^3}}}{-5x^7+\left(111!\right)\cdot \:x}$$

not sure how to approach this limit. I have tried simplifying the function but I can't get it into a usable form. am I missing something when it comes to limit rules on how to approach this?

Comment: You can split into an addition of 3 fractions and find those limits separately, for starters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use L's hopital rule. Also note that (111)! Is as good as any other constant.

> Neglect all terms except the highest Power. ( This is the same if you apply L's hopital too. Answer will be -3/5, as they the powers will get cut. This works because e^ term converges to 1

Comment: this is good to know. Was unaware you could handle factorials in that way.

Comment: Regardless factorial or any function which has a finite value, in such cases we can ignore it as non finite terms are compared with it

Answer (score 7):

First deal with the one complicated part, the term

$$\lim_{x\to-\infty}e^{-\frac{x^3}{(1-x)^3}}\tag{1}$$

in the numerator. Suppose that $x=-u$, where $u$ is positive. Then $1-x=u+1$, and $-x^3=-(-u)^3=u^3$, so

$$e^{-\frac{x^3}{(1-x)^3}}=e^{\frac{u^3}{(u+1)^3}}=e^{\left(\frac{u}{u+1}\right)^3}\,.$$

And $u\to\infty$ as $x\to-\infty$, so you should be able to calculate the limit $(1)$ now.

Once you’ve done that, divide numerator and denominator by $x^7$, and then take the limit as $x\to-\infty$; you should find that many of the terms approach $0$.

Comment: this makes sense, thank you for the explanation! I did not think about u-subing the power on the e.

Comment: @user123456: You’re welcome!

Comment: But the limit doesn't go to 0.......

Comment: @Aatmaj: The limit of the whole expression? No, it doesn’t.

Comment:  yes. Splitting the terms Is a great idea

Comment: thanks sir!.....